# "X wie Y" vs. "X so wie Y"?

Tags: usage

I've been listening to the song "Blau wie das Meer" by Mr. Hurley & die Pulveraffen, and there's one part of the lyrics that uses "so wie" instead of just "wie." I'm wondering if there's a shade of difference in meaning, or if it's just a stylistic choice.

The line is "breit so wie die Ärsche von den Weibern auf Tortuga" would it be equivalent to say "breit wie...", or is there a rule I don't know at play here.

Comment: I don't know the song (and from your quotes from the lyrics I believe it's better not to know such a song), but I guess the word »so« was just added because of the rhythm. Normally you wouldn't use »so« at this place, but poems and lyrics have their own rules. In poems and lyrics such minor errors are acceptable.

Comment: The band sings pirate- and nautical-themed songs, but that one line is about as extreme as the language gets, for the most part. Thanks for the usage info!

Comment: *"The band sings pirate- and nautical-themed songs"* - From what I could read here, I guess they rather sing sexist alcohol-related songs.

Comment: Their playlist definitely does include a few such songs. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant text line is

> Ich bin blau wie das Meer,
>
> voll wie un-ser Lade-raum,
>
> breit **so** wie die Är-sche
>
> von den Wei-bern auf Tor-tu-ga

That **so** is a filler to bring that line to a length of six syllables. (Laderaum has three syllables, but the singer shrinks *Lade-* into one.) Another option had been streching the *wie*.

The last line has eight syllables for distinction.